# Can I replace a 6.3A fuse with an 8A fuse

Tags: fuses

I'm shopping for a Universal Travel Adapter and I've found this one which seems to meet all my requirements. I've used a nice one for years and it recently blew out and it doesn't have a replaceable fuse so I wanted to make sure my next purchase would be more durable with a replaceable fuse.

Unfortunately the website that sells this mentions nothing about the fuse specifications, only that it uses a fuse and comes with a spare one.

On another website displaying the same product it does mention that comes with two 6.3A fuse. And on the picture right here:

[image: universal adapter]

It mentions that the Fuse Rating is 8A MAX.

This confuses me. Why would they include 6.3A fuses which seem to be less standard than 8A ones if the max rating is 8A.

What does this mean for me? I want to order some extra fuses but I can't find any 6.3A fuses but 8A fuses are plentiful. Since it says the Fuse Rating is 8A max then does that mean I can use those?

I'm also concerned with the picture that shows these tiny looking fuses. If you compare that picture with what a 5mmx20mm fuse looks like, those look smaller. Is this just a flaw in the picture. Do you believe this uses standard 5mmx20mm fuses?

Comment: a bigger fuse than the original is not a safe choice

Comment: _"Since it says the Fuse Rating is 8A max then does that mean I can use those?"_ - if you can believe what it says then yes, it should be OK.

Answer (score 2):

A good quality adapter with no moving parts would take a full 16 amps. This  one probably has some thin wires inside to allow the various options, so they've included a fuse.

If you're charging your phone or laptop, you'll never need to change the fuse. If it's for a hairdryer, consider a fixed pair adapter with a higher rating.

In all cases, you shouldn't install a fuse with a higher rating than is specified. If it says 8 A Max, then it's probably OK with an 8 A fuse. More might risk the adapter melting down or catching fire, with a just-too-much overload.